# AngularJS - make variable accessible to whole app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Below is a piece of code that connects with a Firebase database.

I have got a value for `numberOfUsers` and now I would like to use this variable in the html like so {{numberOfUsers}}.

I'm not really sure the best way to do this or if I need to use controllers also? Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm still learning Javascript and Angular.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])

  var userList = new Firebase("https://my-app.firebaseio.com/presence/");

  userList.on("value", function(snap) {
    numberOfUsers = snap.numChildren();
    console.log("Users = " + numberOfUsers);
  });

;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11820/

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a constant to achieve the same as Lucas suggested it. However, instead of creating a constant service for every value you can group then together like this :

```
angular.module("myModule")
.constant("CONST", { "KEY1" : "VALUE1", 
    "KEY2" : "VALUE2"});
```

This way you can gather a bunch of constants together and use it like:

```
CONST.KEY1
CONST.KEY2
```

**EDIT**: Your problem seems to be very different.

First of all you should use the AngularJS flavour of Firebase. Its called [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/index.html). You can find out more about it [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/). I will answer the question of rendering the UI based on Model changes. AngularJS promotes the MVC pattern. You need objects of Service, Controller and View (HTML page) to achieve the functionality you want.

In the example I am providing below, everything is clubbed into one file (index.html) but ideally, the code should be separated.

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="PostCtrl" >
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="post in posts"> <!-- $scope.posts of PostCtrl" -->
                <div>
                    <span>{{post}}</span> <!-- {{}} is used to render data -->
                </div>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
    <script>
        //factory is a type of service. Services are used to write business logic or fetch data from the backend. Your Firebase related calls should come here. 
        angular.module("myapp", []).factory("myService", function($http) {
         return { 
          fetchData: function() { 
        return [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; //can also be a request to the backend returning data.
          }
         };
        });

         //a controller connects a service to the HTML file. $scope service provided by AngularJS is used to achieve this.
        angular.module("myapp").controller("PostCtrl", ["$scope", "myService", function($scope, myService) {
         //posts variable is used in HTML code to retrieve this data.
         $scope.posts = myService.fetchData();
        }]);
    </script>
</div>
```

To learn the basics of AngularJS you can go through [codeschool](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js) tutorials. They are interactive and start from the basics.

Comment: That's good to know. The problem I am having though is getting  numberOfUsers as my Key values. As I don't know how to access numberOfUsers from outside userList.on("value", function(snap) {    });

Answer (score 2):

The formal way to make a value available would be to put it in $rootScope, but it might be better to expose it as part of a service.

Answer (score 1):

Try using constant

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11818/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.constant('numUsers', 4);

    function MyCtrl($scope,numUsers) {
        $scope.name = 'Superhero';
        $scope.numUsers = numUsers;

        $scope.addUser = function(){
            numUsers++;
            $scope.numUsers = numUsers;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok that make sense I have got the example above working but in my case how do I access the value of numberOfUsers instead of 4? As I am getting numberOfUsers is not defined

Comment: Are you asign value to your constant ? Can you show me on a fiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11820/ this is what I want to achieve. I'm trying to get the value of numberOfUsers to display on the page. numberOfUsers is returning an integer.

Comment: @BtrCSowl let`s one step at a time, I saw more the one error in your jsfiddle, 1 - ngRoute need a externeal file https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular-route.js  2 - your firebase module is not found, by those two errors, it wont compile 3 - the constant name is numUser , but you are changing numberOfUsers, which is out of the angular scope